# Angular4 cli routes not working after page refresh?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-routing, angular-cli

If I try routing before ejecting the webpack, it works as expected. As soon as you do ng eject, the application does compiles and runs, but router does not work. The first call is routed properly, but if you try to refresh or navigate to other route, the application returns CANNOT /GET route.

I am using latest angular cli 4.0.0

webpack.config.ts

```
 const path = require('path');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssUrl = require('postcss-url');

const { NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin, LoaderOptionsPlugin } = require('webpack');
const { GlobCopyWebpackPlugin, BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack');
const { CommonsChunkPlugin } = require('webpack').optimize;
const { AotPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

const nodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');
const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","scripts","styles","vendor","main"];
const baseHref = "";
const deployUrl = "";




module.exports = {
  "devtool": "source-map",
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".js"
    ],
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "resolveLoader": {
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "entry": {
    "main": [
      "./src\\main.ts"
    ],
    "polyfills": [
      "./src\\polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "script-loader!./node_modules\\jquery\\dist\\jquery.min.js",
      "script-loader!./node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\js\\bootstrap.min.js"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "./src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech.min.css",
      "./src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech-layout.css",
      "./node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css",
      "./node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.min.css"
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "[id].chunk.js"
  },
  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "enforce": "pre",
        "test": /\.js$/,
        "loader": "source-map-loader",
        "exclude": [
          /\/node_modules\//
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": /\.json$/,
        "loader": "json-loader"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.html$/,
        "loader": "raw-loader"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(eot|svg)$/,
        "loader": "file-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(jpg|png|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani)$/,
        "loader": "url-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]&limit=10000"
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech-layout.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.min.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech-layout.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.min.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech-layout.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.min.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader",
          "less-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech-layout.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.min.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader",
          "stylus-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"paths\":[]}"
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech-layout.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.min.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech-layout.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.min.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader",
    "sass-loader"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech-layout.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.min.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader",
    "less-loader"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\assets\\public\\css\\synaptech-layout.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.min.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader",
    "stylus-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"paths\":[]}"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "test": /\.ts$/,
        "loader": "@ngtools/webpack"
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    new NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new GlobCopyWebpackPlugin({
      "patterns": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "globOptions": {
        "cwd": "D:\\angular-cli-example\\cli-test4 - Copy\\cli-test4\\src",
        "dot": true,
        "ignore": "**/.gitkeep"
      }
    }),
    new ProgressPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      "template": "./src\\index.html",
      "filename": "./index.html",
      "hash": false,
      "inject": true,
      "compile": true,
      "favicon": false,
      "minify": false,
      "cache": true,
      "showErrors": true,
      "chunks": "all",
      "excludeChunks": [],
      "title": "Webpack App",
      "xhtml": true,
      "chunksSortMode": function sort(left, right) {
        let leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
        let rightindex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
        if (leftIndex > rightindex) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (leftIndex < rightindex) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    }),
    new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({}),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": "inline",
      "minChunks": null
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": "vendor",
      "minChunks": (module) => module.resource && module.resource.startsWith(nodeModules),
      "chunks": [
        "main"
      ]
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      "filename": "[name].bundle.css",
      "disable": true
    }),
    new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      "sourceMap": false,
      "options": {
        "postcss": [
          autoprefixer(),
          postcssUrl({"url": (URL) => {
            // Only convert root relative URLs, which CSS-Loader won't process into require().
            if (!URL.startsWith('/') || URL.startsWith('//')) {
                return URL;
            }
            if (deployUrl.match(/:\/\//)) {
                // If deployUrl contains a scheme, ignore baseHref use deployUrl as is.
                return `${deployUrl.replace(/\/$/, '')}${URL}`;
            }
            else if (baseHref.match(/:\/\//)) {
                // If baseHref contains a scheme, include it as is.
                return baseHref.replace(/\/$/, '') +
                    `/${deployUrl}/${URL}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
            }
            else {
                // Join together base-href, deploy-url and the original URL.
                // Also dedupe multiple slashes into single ones.
                return `/${baseHref}/${deployUrl}/${URL}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
            }
        }})
        ],
        "sassLoader": {
          "sourceMap": false,
          "includePaths": []
        },
        "lessLoader": {
          "sourceMap": false
        },
        "context": ""
      }
    }),
    new AotPlugin({
      "mainPath": "main.ts",
      "hostReplacementPaths": {
        "environments\\environment.ts": "environments\\environment.ts"
      },
      "exclude": [],
      "tsConfigPath": "src\\tsconfig.app.json",
      "skipCodeGeneration": true
    })
  ],
  "node": {
    "fs": "empty",
    "global": true,
    "crypto": "empty",
    "tls": "empty",
    "net": "empty",
    "process": true,
    "module": false,
    "clearImmediate": false,
    "setImmediate": false
  }
};
```

Please any one let me know what to do

Comment: I have same issue,,

Comment: Can you show us your webpack.config?

Comment: I added config file, please find it

Comment: Try to configure `devServer` option like it did here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v1.0.0/packages/%40angular/cli/tasks/serve.ts#L136-L152 historyApiFallback

Comment: in webpack.config.ts in which place I have to configure devserver option

Comment: Here is example https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-build-examples/blob/master/ngtools-webpack/webpack.config.js#L53-L63 But maybe you need to specify `index` for `historyApiFallback`

Comment: like `historyApiFallback: { index: 'index.html' .`..

Comment: I did nt understood , can u please explain breifly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141867/discussion-between-mahesh-peddi-and-yurzui).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `devServer` option:

```
module.exports = {
    "devtool": "source-map",
    ...
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
};
```

From documentation

> If you are using the HTML5 history API you probably need to serve your
>   index.html in place of 404 responses, which can be done by setting
>   historyApiFallback: true

https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#the-historyapifallback-option

You can also take a look how angular-cli configures `devServer` option

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v1.0.0/packages/%40angular/cli/tasks/serve.ts#L136-L152